# CSS3 Radial Gradient pulsating waves on Macbook Pro OSX 10.10 using Chrome

Tags: macos, css

I'm experiencing issues with the following code

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #706358, #302B29)
```

The gradient is showing up correctly but with pulsing waves on MacBook Pro's, from what I can tell.

I have a attached an image, but of course you need a macbook pro to be able to view the issue.

[image: Issue]

Comment: If  photoshop is running the issue will be resolved. Maybe driver issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known issue of Google Chrome: [see here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226753)

At the moment there are no fixes, your only choices are...

- **Disable** the automatic **GPU-Switching** on your Macbook Pro
- ...or use **another browser**. Safari and Firefox are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen with all gradients, or just this one?

When you mentioned "pulsating waves", I instantly thought of the "moire effect".

Some displays combined with some color bit depth settings can render this effect.

Comment: From what I can tell it looks like it could be a hardware issue, If I open up photoshop the waves just disappear.